# get count of all users for particular category and rank them

Tags: mysql, sql

how do I get count of each user contribution/appearing for that particular category.The table below has user,category .I am looking for count of hoe many times all users have contributed/appeared in  the table below and rank them.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4458/2

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
user varchar(255),
 category int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (user, category ) VALUES
('1', '1'),
('1', '2'),
('1', '3'),
('1', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1');
```

Response like: Search for category where its '1'

```
user  category    count    rank

1       1         2        1
2       1         2        2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT USER,
       category,
       count(*) AS num
FROM tblA
WHERE category=1
GROUP BY USER,
         category
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

*demo*: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4458/10/0

Comment: What is the criteria to rank ? I see both users with same count in categories.

Comment: how can I add another column with rank and have 1 and 2 and so on based on the count ?

Comment: for rank see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9188/1  rank them 1,2,3 also if the case where both count is same then also the user who is above will have lower rank.Eg. user 1 and 2 both have 2 so user 1 will be rank 1 and user 2 will be rank 2.

Comment: @DhruvPathak Can you please tell me how do I do this ?

Comment: @jason if the answer worked for you upvote it and also accept it :Dhruy your answer is relevant

Comment: @humphrey I am unable to rank them as in the question I had asked I would also like to rank them currently I am getting count but how do I get another column next to count where it has them ranked based on num

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
SELECT
  i.*,
  CASE 
    WHEN @prev_value = i.num THEN @rank_count
    ELSE @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
  END AS rank
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user,category,COUNT(*) AS num
  FROM tblA
  WHERE category=1 
  GROUP BY user,category 
  ORDER BY num DESC
) i;
```